# summary statistics from a list

Tags: r, list

I'm trying to create summary stats from a list. I have mock data, created 3 sub-sets of data, saved it to csv and imported it, now i'm trying to calculate a mean for each column in each csv as a list.

```
examples_mean <- map(examples, function (data_df) {
  data_df <- data_df %>%
    summarise(vars(column1, column2), mean(mean))

  return(data_df)
})

examples_mean
```

I tried using lapply() and various other suggestion from stackoverflow

but the only one that doesn't give an error/ warning is my code above, but returns this, below,
which is what I need, but its missing the values in the mean column:

```
> examples_mean
$`data/example_1.csv`
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  `vars(column1, column2)` `mean(mean)`
  <quos>                       <dbl>
1 column1                        NA
2 column2                        NA

$`data/example_2.csv`
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  `vars(column1, column2)` `mean(mean)`
  <quos>                       <dbl>
1 column1                        NA
2 column2                        NA

$`data/example_3.csv`
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  `vars(column1, column2)` `mean(mean)`
  <quos>                         <dbl>
1 column1                         NA
2 column2                         NA
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some syntax errors.  If the intention is to loop over the columns `column1`, `column2` in each of the datasets in the `list`, loop over the `list` with `map`, then select the `column1`, `column2` and loop `across` those columns in `summarise` to get the `mean` of the column

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map(examples, ~ 
     .x %>%
       summarise(across(c(column1, column2), ~ mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE)))

 )
```

Comment: Brilliant thanks! the "~.x" and "~ mean(.x)" are new to me - can you explain (to an R newbie)

Comment: @Sarah Those are anonymous function syntax in tidyverse.  You can either use those lambda or the generic `function(x)` (as you showed).  I changed it to this as this is more concise.   With `tidyverse`, `.x` will be the default argument if there is only one argument.  If there are 2 for example in map2 or imap, there will be `.x` and `.y` .  In `pmap`, with multiple argumentts, it can be `..1`, `..2`, `..3` etc..